# How to 'copy' and 'paste special' 'values only' if the cells are highlight orange (or any colour) by combining these two scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have these two scripts which work great separately. The freezeValues() function can copy a cell which has its value through a formula and paste the value only back in place (to remove the formula and keep the value), this can be done on a range of cells.

The clearOrange() function will clear any cells that have the background colour orange, this is great when used with condition formatting.

I need the functionality of both of these scripts to be able to copy and paste in place any cells that are highlighted orange, to effectively remove formulas for ranges of cells. I am new to java script and full disclosure these scripts are not mine. Is this even possible?

```
function freezeValues() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('DIARY 2017');  // or whatever name
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();    // assuming your data appears in A1-Z1 

  range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly: true});
}

function clearOrange() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('DIARY 2017');
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var bgColors = range.getBackgrounds();
  for (var i=0; i<bgColors.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<bgColors[i].length; j++) {
      if (bgColors[i][j] === '#ff9900') {
        range.getCell(i+1,j+1).clearContent();
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a combination of the above, freezeOrange. It's mostly like the clearOrange function except that the `clear` step is replaced by copy and paste values.

```
function freezeOrange() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('DIARY 2017');
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var bgColors = range.getBackgrounds();
  for (var i=0; i<bgColors.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<bgColors[i].length; j++) {
      if (bgColors[i][j] === '#ff9900') {
        var cell = range.getCell(i+1,j+1);
        cell.copyTo(cell, {contentsOnly: true});
      }
    }
  }  
}
```